# Navegação com Xamarin Forms padrão MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms, cross-platform, mvvm

Comecei recentemente a estudar Xamarin Forms. Tenho uma dúvida que poderá aqui ser esclarecida: como navegar entre páginas usando MVVM? A navegação deverá ficar na **vm** ou na **view**?

**Exemplo**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     x:Class="GeoMobile.Views.Login">
     <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="GEO Mobile" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="Email" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding Senha}" Placeholder="Senha" />
        <Button Text="Entrar" Command="{Binding Entrar}" />
        <Button Text="Registrar" />
     </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Login.cs**

```
public partial class Login : ContentPage
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new LoginVM(Entrar);
    }

    public async void Entrar()
    {
        Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new Master__(), this);
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

E na minha **vm**:

```
public class LoginVM : ObservableBase
{
    private string _email;

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        protected set
        {
            _email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _senha;

    public string Senha
    {
        get { return _senha; }
        set
        {
            _senha = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Command Entrar { get; private set; }
    private Action loginOk;

    private void login()
    {
        //checagem antes de ir para a proxima pagina
        loginOk();
    }

    public LoginVM(Action loginOk)
    {
        this.loginOk = loginOk;
        Entrar = new Command(login);
    }
}
```

Consegui a navegação passando uma action no construtor da vm, mas preciso implementar outra navegação para o botão registrar, mas para isso já teria que passar outra action no construtor e acredito que isso não seria uma boa prática.

Se colocar a navegação na vm, o processo de software testing vai ser dificultado. Qual a melhor maneira de contornar o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por definição creio que a navegação deva ser feita na sua VM, sua View só deveria ser utilizada para os fins de layout. Claro que isso não é uma regra e se você tiver necessidade de utilizar algo na sua View por qualquer problema que esteja ocorrendo na VM, você não vai deixar seu app bugando por isso, mas pelo padrão mvvm creio que o mais correto seria na sua vm.

Geralmente eu crio um "service" e na minha base view model eu o utilizo por injeção de dependência. Funciona bem, nunca tive problemas.

Recomendo esse [Video](https://youtu.be/Yr7pGCsGmQ0/) do Angelo Belchior , ele ilustra bem o que eu escrevi acima.

Comment: Ótimo Brian, inclusive havia visto esse vídeo ontem. Show de boa, exatamente o que eu precisava.

Comment: Show! Recomendo o Prism como framework mvvm, ele resolve a parte de navegação de forma brilhante :)

Answer (score 0):

Para quem estiver com a mesma dificuldade que eu, encontrei um ótimo tutorial, vale a pena dar uma conferida...

http://xamarinbr.azurewebsites.net/navegacao-entre-paginas-e-display-alert-com-mvvm-e-xamarin-forms/